# how to create a simple node server that compresses static files using gzip

Tags: node.js, express, compression, gzip, http-compression

I've been on this for hours..

the first thing i did was follow [this](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content) tutorial which had this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// New call to compress content
app.use(express.compress());    
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3333);
```

naturally the code was outdated.. and I got this error:

```
Error: Most middleware (like compress) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
```

so i updated the code to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var compression = require('compression')

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/_public' ));    

app.listen(3333);
```

which worked fine.. but I saw no evidence of compression (how do i know? by viewing the chrome dev tools response headers:

[image]

it doesn't have the gzip `content-encoding` header like the one in the tutorial:

[image]

So tried using the [zlib](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) library instead:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var maxAge  = 31557600000;
var zlib = require('zlib');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/_public' ));

app.get('/*', function(req,res)
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/_public/index.html').pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(output);
});

app.listen(3333);
```

but that didn't work out either.. and i'm pretty much left bald at this point.. any help?

p.s. the compression [docs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/compression) say you can provide zlib options, but fail to provide any examples/explanation.

---

**update:**
the question has been fully answered and marked as such (i hate moving target questions).. but I can't help but asking: and so how can you verify how much of your original payload got trimmed as a result of gzip compression? Since naturally the compressing/decompressing happens behinds the scenes and as such chrome dev tools will report the original size of the file in its networking tab:

[image]

Comment: What is the exact file size of your `index.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your setup, using the `compression` module, is correct. I just don't think it compresses the files during development.

Try setting the `NODE_ENV` to "production", e.g.

`$ NODE_ENV="production"
$ node server.js`

**EDIT**
To your follow up question.

Essentially what you are seeing in Chrome Dev Tools is the result of the compressed gzip compression. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165729/236564) describes it better then I can:

> "Size" is the number of bytes on the wire, and "content" is the actual size of the resource

gzip compression reduces the "on the wire" size of the resource.

So, in your example, there will be 450 KB for the end user to download.

Comment: interesting.. so `npm start` is the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11716667/766570) as running `node %nodefile%.js`.. b/c the script above is in a `server.js` file.. i'll just run `$NODE_ENV='produciton';node server.js`

Comment: it worked! but simply running `node server.js` where `server.js` has all the code above doesn't work.. i had to actually update my `package.json` and put `  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"}` in it then it worked! i'll award you the correct answer since you answered my question above.. but i'll also add a little follow up question if you don't mind

Comment: Sure, what's the follow up? I'll modify the answer to use `node server.js`

Answer (score 5):

zlib.createGunzip() is for decompressing.

I think that using headers and streams works.

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip' });
 fs.createReadStream('_public/index.html').pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, specify **threshold** value for small files compression (under 1kb) :

```
app.use(compression({ threshold: 0 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as well, used the `compression` module, like so :

```
const app = express();
app.use(compression({threshold : 0}));
app.use(express.static(path));
```

I tested it by devtools looking for `Content-Encoding: gzip` on the response header but without success.

Apparently chrome cached the files after the first request, so when refreshing again I couldn't see the `Content-Encoding: gzip` cause it retrieved the file from the cache.

Therefore I **hard refreshed** the page (Chrome ignores the cache and will load all resources from the web page again.) **by doing Ctrl+Shift+R** or from UI by right clicking refresh icon and selecting hard refresh.
Then I managed to see the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header.