# Express 4.x compression

Tags: node.js, express, compression

I have tested my local web server with Google's PageSpeed chrome extension. One of the results was that my web server doesn't have compression enabled. I am using node js on the backend with express 4.x. I googled a bit to find a solution to compress data and I found https://github.com/expressjs/compression a middleware for express. I tried to use it like this:

```
    var app                 = express();
    var compression         = require('compression');
    var server              = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(CONFIG.PORT);
    app.use(compression());
```

Even though I did this pageSpeed is still recommending to compress data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What data did it recommend to compress? `compression` middleware only compresses response

Comment: I have made some changes and I am putting compression as the first middleware to use and it is compressing all the data sent by the server for example /api/mongoModel but it is not compressing .js, .css and .html files.

Comment: I don't think that it will compress static files.

Comment: Checkout related questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340612/how-to-create-a-simple-node-server-that-compresses-static-files-using-gzip) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370478/express-gzip-static-content)

Answer (score 17):

```
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

Put JS, CSS, HTML files below the `public` directory and they will be compressed.

Comment: The order makes all the difference !

Comment: One line of code reduced my initial loading time to half. How cool is that!

Answer (score -2):

//use compression to speedup page load

app.use(compression());

app.use('app', function (req, res, next) {});

Comment: please take a look at [answer] there is markdown to make an answer more readable