# node and nodejs commands do nothing while npm works

Tags: node.js

I'm learning NodeJS, I made a script using `express-generator`. It works great when I run `npm start app.js`:

```
root@server:~ $ npm start app.js 

> nodejs@0.0.0 start /root/nodejs
> node ./bin/www "app.js"
```

However, if I try to use `node` or `nodejs`, it doesn't work at all:

```
root@server:~ $ node app.js 
root@server:~ $ node app
root@server:~ $ nodejs app.js 
root@server:~ $ nodejs app
root@server:~ $
```

Here are the versions I am using:

```
root@server:~ $ nodejs -v
v8.11.4
root@server:~ $ node -v
v8.11.4
root@server:~ $ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: please check your start script in package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

For express project created using `express-generator`, this command will work `node ./bin/www` instead of `node app.js`. In package.json you will see that `"scripts": {"start": "node ./bin/www"}`, which start your project with `npm start`. By default only `node` command works on terminal/CMD like `node --version` and `nodejs` do nothing. `npm` is `node package manager` and gets installed when you install `nodejs` on your system. `npm --version` will show the npm version

Answer (score 0):

please check your package.json. default command to start the project is `"start"`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
```

whereas the command used for `node -v` is for the node application and not related to the project, I mean related to the scripting of the project.

if possible check this [npm start vs node app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362021/npm-start-vs-node-app-js)

you should go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs

its a dev guide from Mozilla. it will make you better understand the concepts related to express.