# Dowload google cloud storage files from cloud bucket continuously looping when using npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I'm trying to download to google cloud storage logs from bucket.The files only download once when using node XXX.js in linux. When I use npm start, it non-stop downloading the same files. May I know the reason behind ?

Trying to add process.exit(o) not working

```
async function main() {
await 
 client
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .getFiles(options)
  .then(results => {
    const files = results[0];

    console.log('Files:');
    files.forEach(file => {

    const formatFileName = file.name.replace( /\//g ,'_');
    var new_str = formatFileName.split(":")[0];


    fs.open(new_str+'.json', 'w', function (err, file) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('File is opened in write mode.');
            fs.close(file, function () {
                 console.log('File is closed.');
            })
    });

    const destOptions = {

           destination: +new_str+'.json'
    };


    file.download(destOptions);


    fs.rename(new_str+'.json', new_str+'.txt', function(err) {
        if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    });

    console.log(file.name);
    return code;
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    code = 1;
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
}

main().then((res) => {
    console.log('here');
    return process.exit(0);
}).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given the description you're given, my hypothesis is that when using `npm start`, it will be running the same script x times, whereas `node foo.js` will  run the script only once. `npm start` runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's "start" property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified on the "scripts" object, it will run `node server.js`.

More info about `npm start` **[here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start)**

You can also see **[npm start vs. node app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362021/npm-start-vs-node-app-js)** for more details.

> > > **Answer: I solved the problem by changing the config.yml watch --> false. Since I download the file to the directory and watch detect file changes. Hence, it keep reloading the program.**

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem by changing the config.yml watch --> false. Since I download the file to the directory and watch detect file changes. Hence, it keep reloading the program.