# Why it's not working my localhost when I run an Angular/React project?

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, localhost

When I run `npm start` in a React or Angular project, the page stuck loading forever in blank.

I have tried to reinstall node, change ports and other things, and nothing. It's very strange. My OS is MacOS 10.14.6 and It started to fail suddenly days ago. And I have in my localhost mysql, apache and php running without problems.

There are not error messages.

-----***EDIT***-----

I tried to create new React and Angular apps too but localhost still not working.

-----***EDIT 2***-----

Sometimes, randomly in Safari incognito mode works, but I have disabled cache and try incognito mode on Chrome too, but nothing. Firefox is not working too.
I am trying the correct port and there are not messages in console.

Comment: We cannot help you debugging with no clue. Since it is not a common problem, we need way more informations on what happens to identify the root cause. You would have more luck asking a workmate to have a look with you.

Comment: Can you provide the content of the package.json. There must be a "scripts" section:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716421/difference-between-npm-start-node-app-js-when-starting-app

Comment: @camen6ert hello, I tried to create new apps to and there is not changes.

package.json script of React:
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

and Angular:

"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port=4222",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },

Comment: Are you trying to reach the correct port? http://localhost:4222 ?

Comment: Ok looks good, Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Riscie yep, for sure :) Furthermore I have been trying running Angular and React on different ports at the same time.

Comment: @camen6ert nothing. Network tabs shows localhost 'loading'.

Comment: Sometimes, randomly in Safari incognito mode works, but I have disabled cache and try incognito mode on Chrome too, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**FALSE ALARM**

It was the antivirus but I don't know exactly why. Maybe was some extra security, but It's strange because localhost of Apache works for example.