# Why we don't mention file name like node app.js for npm start?

Tags: reactjs, npm, web-development-server

When we work with react, to start a server we use npm start command, why we don't use file name like App.js or index.js with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716421/difference-between-npm-start-node-app-js-when-starting-app#11716667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are working with create-react-app? The command `npm start` in this setup will start a webpack-dev-server. The starting file (index.js) is specified in the webpack config file, that is used by this server. So the file has to be specified, it is just abstracted away from you.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access webpack config file?

Comment: I hope this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files

Comment: However, if you want to customise the webpack config of create-react-app, there are some steps needed, see: https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc

Answer (score 0):

In the package.json file, you have a property called "scripts", there you've got every scripts you can run by typing "npm run" in the console, if you take a look, "start" is one of them, and it usually runs a "node [filename]" kinda command. So, you are basically running an alias command.

Also, the reason you don't type "npm run start" its because a convention with the "start" command to be the default command, but I don't really know the specifics on that.